# How can I change key in the array on the php?

Tags: php, arrays, key

My array like this :

```
$arr = array('chelsea.jpg', 'arsenal.jpg');
```

If I run : `echo '<pre>';print_r($arr);echo '</pre>';`

The result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => chelsea.jpg
    [1] => arsenal.jpg
)
```

I want to change the key. So the result to be like this :

```
Array
(
    [cover1] => chelsea.jpg
    [cover2] => arsenal.jpg
)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? There are various ways to do this.

Comment: Technically you cannot change the name of existing array keys.  However you can assign values to new keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the classic `foreach`

```
$arr = array('chelsea.jpg', 'arsenal.jpg');

$final = array();

foreach( $arr as $key => $val ) {
    //Notice that $key + 1 -> because the first key of a simple array is 0
    //You are assigning here the NEW key inside []
    $final[ "cover" . ( $key + 1 ) ] = $val;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $final );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to

```
Array
(
    [cover1] => chelsea.jpg
    [cover2] => arsenal.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = array( 'cover1' => 'chelsea.jpg', 'cover2' => 'arsenal.jpg' );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_combine().

```
print_r(array_combine(array('cover1', 'cover2'), array('chelsea.jpg', 'arsenal.jpg')));
```

To generate keys dynamically -

```
$values = array('chelsea.jpg', 'arsenal.jpg');
// Generate keys depending on the count of values
$keys = array_map(function($k) {
    return 'cover' . $k;
}, range(1, count($values)));

print_r(array_combine($keys, $values));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [cover1] => chelsea.jpg
    [cover2] => arsenal.jpg
)
```